# Combination with multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, combinations

I have the following **three lists of unequal lengths:**

```
a = [2.13, 5.48,-0.58]

b = [4.17, 1.12, 2.13, 3.48,-1.01,-1.17]

c = [6.73, 8, 12]

d = [(2.13,2.13),(5.48,-1.17),(-0.58,4.17)]

e = [(4.17,12),(2.13,6.73)]
```

I need to create a combination_abc = [ (x,y,z) for x in a
                                                 for y in b
                                                for z in c] **such that (x,y) is not equal to d and (y,z) is not equal to e**

Comment: Under `(x,y) is not equal to d` you mean that `d` doesn't contain `(x,y)`?

Comment: As a side not, your comprehension might be easier to read as `itertools.product(a, b, c)`, instead of doing the nesting explicitly with three `for` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correct, just add if-statement into your list comprehension:

```
[(x, y, z) for x in a for y in b for z in c if (x, y) not in d and (y, z) not in e]
```

Also you can use `itertools.product` for simplicity:

```
from itertools import product

[(x, y, z) for x, y, z in product(a, b, c) if (x, y) not in d and (y, z) not in e]
```